# Silverstripe: loop over many_many || belongs_many_many relation list

Tags: silverstripe, relation

I have two classes **Project** and **Developer**. One developer can work in several projects, one project can be processed by several developers, so it's a n-m-relation. In my database there's a table **project_developers**, which is the mapping table for those two classes. This mapping table includes the ProjectIDs and the DeveloperIDs.

```
<?php
class Developer extends Member {
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Projects' => 'Project'
    );
}

<?php
class Project extends DataObject {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Developers' => 'Developer'
    );
}
```

I want to display all projects of one developer.

Displaying all projects works like this:

```
return Project::get();
```

But I don't know, how i get only the projects of one specific developer. I want to filter the mapping table for a specific developerID.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred method is to have your developer already. If you only have a `DeveloperID`, use it to get your `Developer` first:

`$developer = Developer::get()->byID($DeveloperID);`

Then you can easily get the `Projects` from the `Developer`:

```
$MyDevelopersProjects = $developer->Projects();
foreach( $MyDevelopersProjects as $Project ) {
   ... 
}
```

There are other ways to do this manually such as using a `->join(...)` and a `->filter(...)` after a `Projects::get()`, but I wouldn't recommend that route.

There is also `DataList::Relation($relationName)` that could be used to get a result, but I've never had to use them so not really sure of how it would go.

Comment: thx AlphaCactus!! Now it works. I'm happy :)
A few days ago I wrote $developer->Projects(); and then my IDE told me that the ->Projects(); commando wasn't found, but I didn't try it out to run. 
But this commando works.

Comment: foreach( $developer->Projects() as $Project ) should work as well

Comment: @jberculo Do you know if there is any performance hit to use your suggested syntax?  I have read before that something like count($someArray) can be slow, so I always assumed that calling a function would be slower, if done many times, than to store it in a variable. I don't really know for sure though.

Comment: @crappidy the IDE is there to help, but many times I've found the IDE does not fully support the intricate ways in which a framework such as Silverstripe uses the PHP language.  PHP is well known for being convoluted.  I recommend: take your IDE alerts more as guidelines rather than truth.

Comment: @AlphaCactus In both cases, PHP will call the function only once, so they are basically the same